# How can I prevent print slides when the value changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a fighting game with HP bars etc. I did almost everything except HP bars. I simply can't stop it slides when the first HP bar's value changes. How can I fix it?

```
def get_hpbar(hpoints, hpoints2, name1, name2):
bar1 = hpoints2 / 2
bar2 = hpoints / 2
print(name1, " " * 64, name2)
print("HP[{}]:".format(hpoints2), int(bar1) * "|", "        ", end="")
print("HP[{}]:".format(hpoints), int(bar2) * "|")
```

[Example of unwanted situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kq8M.png)

[Example of wanted display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbO3L.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're relying on character count for alignment, you likely want to "pad" the hp bar with empty slots (spaces) to keep them at 100 size, while reducing the printed characters at will.

e.g.

```
|||||||||| < before hit
||||||     < after hit (fill with spaces)
```

You can use the string method `ljust` to help you with that. e.g.

```py
hp_bar = ('|' * hp).ljust(100, ' ')
print(hp_bar)
```

The `ljust` method justifies content to the left (ljust = left justify) by padding the right with character until the string reaches the specified size.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to solve the problem without worrying about formatting is just add spaces to make the gap constant.

```
def get_hpbar(hpoints, hpoints2, name1, name2):
    bar1 = hpoints2 / 2
    bar2 = hpoints / 2
    print(name1, " " * 64, name2)
    print("HP[{}]:".format(hpoints2), int(bar1) * "|", int(50-bar1) * " " ,"        ", end="")
    print("HP[{}]:".format(hpoints), int(bar2) * "|")
```